# Automatically replace all excessively large vector graphs with rasterized versions?

Tags: front-end, rasterize

Some of my notebooks are huge because vector graphics are taking unexpectedly large size. This also makes scrolling slow.

For instance code below takes a few seconds to generate an image which is 10MB in size.

Is there a way to automatically replace all such vector graphics with rasterized version?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
SF = StringForm;
gaussianSampler[diag_] := With[{d = Length[diag]},
   Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    Module[{vals, diagSqrt},
     diagSqrt = Sqrt[diag];
     vals = 
      diagSqrt*# & /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, d}]]]];


(* Generates plot for Gaussian SGD with cov eigenvalues \
1^-p,2^-p,...,d^-p, by using step size a *) 
generatePlot[p_, d_, a_] := Module[{},
   B = 10;
   numSteps = 2000;
   ones = ConstantArray[1., d];
   h = Table[i^-p, {i, 1, d}];
   sampler = gaussianSampler[h];
   W0 = sampler[B];
   
   step[w_, x_] = w - a x x . w;
   batchStep[W_] := MapThread[step, {W, sampler[B]}];
   traj = NestList[batchStep, W0, numSteps]; (* numSteps x B x d *)
   
   errorNorms2 = Total[traj*traj, {3}]; (* numSteps x B *)
   numQuantiles = 100;
   compress[l_] := Quantile[l, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 1/numQuantiles];
   
   meanPlot = 
    ListLinePlot[Total[errorNorms2, {2}]/B, ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
      PlotLegends -> {"mean"}];
   filling = 
    Table[i -> {numQuantiles + 2 - i}, {i, 1, numQuantiles/2}];
   distPlot = 
    ListLinePlot[Transpose[compress /@ errorNorms2], 
     ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Filling -> filling, 
     FillingStyle -> Directive[
       Opacity[.1], EdgeForm[]], PlotStyle -> {Directive[Gray, Thin]}];
   
   Show[distPlot, meanPlot, 
    AxesLabel -> {"t", "||e\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(||\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
    PlotLabel -> SF["e=e-x<e,x>", d], ImageSize -> Large]
   
   ];

a = 2.4212495210368360429927801314282259331288428340678678473778384243\
45397835692066559296652232682365322;
generatePlot[1, 1, a]

notebookCellData = 
  ResourceFunction["NotebookCellData", 
   ResourceSystemBase -> 
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/api/1.0"];
Take[ReverseSortBy[
  notebookCellData[
   EvaluationNotebook[], {"CellByteCount"}], #CellByteCount &], 
 UpTo[5]]
```